# JUnit says my test method "could not be resolved to a unique method"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

Trying to learn JUnit 5 with IntelliJ IDEA. Created a test class and trying to test one method. Here's the message (see third line):

```
INFO: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter]
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException:'DirectoryTest#directory2bytes' could not be resolved to a unique method
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.lambda$selectMethod$1(DiscoverySelectors.java:131)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod(DiscoverySelectors.java:130)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.createSelector(JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.java:111)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.java:86)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:46)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 254
Empty test suite.
```

I can't understand why the method can't be resolved: It compiles and it's definitely there:

```
@Test
void directory2bytes( ) {
    testBytes = testDir.directory2bytes();
    for( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.print( testBytes[i] + " ")
    }
    System.out.println( );
}
```

And I have defined this:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp( ) {
    testDir = new Directory( )
    testBytes = new byte[1000];
}
```

Update: quitting and relaunching IntelliJ IDEA, I am now getting messages that the imported symbol "junit" can't be resolved, along with the various annotations "@beforeEach", "afterEach" and "Test".

Update 2: found and fixed a missing semicolon in test class, but no change. Note: there are compile errors in some of the classes that I'm not testing, but I have the test Run configuration set to "Build, no error check". Is this right? I have also tried to create the same test (with a different class name) using JUnit 4, but that doesn't work either.

Here are first few lines of error message:

```
Dec 07, 2016 9:51:41 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
INFO: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter, junit-vintage]
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: DirectoryTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.MethodSelector.lambda$lazyLoadJavaClass$0(MethodSelector.java:154)
```

Comment: Tried to add this but apparently it didn't record: I'm now getting the message  "Library JUnit5 has broken path" in the Project Structure's Dependencies tab.

Comment: Can you please create a scaled down example project on GitHub that demonstrates the error you are encountering and nothing more?

Comment: Also, have you tried creating a new project in IDEA to see if that somehow fixes the problems you have in your existing project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently compile errors in noninvolved classes were causing the problems. Even though I had specified Build without error check, the tests wouldn't run.

Most of these errors were simply "missing return statement", which I eliminated for the time being by adding a meaningless value return. This was an annoying waste of time.

All I have to say is, the error messages were fantastically UNhelpful in tracking down the problem!

Comment: Also, check your JUnit version, mine was not up-to-date, causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Due to a [bug](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/331), M2 does not support selecting methods with parameters. This is fixed in M3. However, to use M3 in IntelliJ IDEA out of the box, you need 2016.3.1 which will be released next week. There's a [workaround](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/586#issuecomment-265012600) to use M3 with the current version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I'm using the 2016.3.1 RC build (for Mac)

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 2016.3.6 on Mac. On my POM, the dependency artifact `junit-jupiter-api` specified version it was `RELEASE` as this was imported automatically by IntelliJ. I follow @Marc Philipp advice and changed it to `5.0.0-M3` all is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Methods annotated with `Test`, `Before`, `After`, etc. must be declared `public`. Your methods are using the default visibility (also known as package-protected), which aren't visible to JUnit, and thus cannot be executed. Make them public and try again.

Comment: Thank you, but no luck (and if these test methods must be declared public, why doesn't the system do that for you?)  Still get the same message.